# Different behavior of go exec for different shell commands

Tags: go, cmd, interactive-shell

I'm trying to use different shell commands for a console go application, and for some reason the behavior is different for the following interactive shells.

This code prints result of a mongoDB query:

```
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "mongo --quiet --host=localhost blog")
stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()

stdin, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()
stdoutScanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)

go func() {
    for stdoutScanner.Scan() {
        println(stdoutScanner.Text())
    }
}()

cmd.Start()
io.WriteString(stdin, "db.getCollection('posts').find({status:'ACTIVE'}).itcount()\n")

//can't finish command, need to reuse it for other queries
//stdin.Close()
//cmd.Wait()

time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
```

But the same code for Neo4J shell does not print anything:

```
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "cypher-shell -u neo4j -p 121314 --format plain")
stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()

stdin, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()
stdoutScanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)

go func() {
    for stdoutScanner.Scan() {
        println(stdoutScanner.Text())
    }
}()

cmd.Start()
io.WriteString(stdin, "match (n) return count(n);\n")

//can't finish the command, need to reuse it for other queries
//stdin.Close()
//cmd.Wait()
time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
```

What is the difference? How can I make the second one work? (without closing the command)

P.S
Neo4J works fine when I print directly to `os.Stdout`:

```
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "cypher-shell -u neo4j -p 121314 --format plain")

cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout

stdin, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()

cmd.Start()
io.WriteString(stdin, "match (n) return count(n);\n")

//stdin.Close()
//cmd.Wait()
time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
```

Comment: If it works with the second variant, then cypher-shell prints to stderr, not stdout. The cmd.Stdout assignment is undone by calling StdinPipe.

Comment: @Peter I tried to remove `cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr`, but it still prints the result in second variant.

Comment: I misstook StdinPipe for StdoutPipe. Nevermind my earlier comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the input to `cypher-shell` is **not** an (interactive) terminal, it expects to read the *entire* input and execute it as a single script. “Entire input” means “everything until EOF”. This is typical for REPL programs: for example, [`python`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/python3.1.html) behaves like this, too.

So your Cypher code doesn’t even begin executing until you `stdin.Close()`. Your `cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout` example appears to work because `stdin` is implicitly closed when your Go program exits, and only **then** does `cypher-shell` execute your code and print to stdout, which is still connected to your terminal.

You should probably structure your process differently. For example, can’t you run a new `cypher-shell` for each query?

**However**, if all else fails, you can work around this by fooling `cypher-shell` into thinking that its stdin [is a terminal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html). This is called a “pty”, and you can do it in Go with [`github.com/kr/pty`](https://godoc.org/github.com/kr/pty). **The catch** is that this also makes `cypher-shell` print prompts and echo your input, which you will have to detect and discard if you wish to process the output programmatically.

```
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "cypher-shell -u neo4j -p 121314 --format plain")
f, _ := pty.Start(cmd)
stdoutScanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
cmd.Start()

// Give it some time to start, then read and discard the startup banner.
time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
f.Read(make([]byte, 4096))

go func() {
    for stdoutScanner.Scan() {
        println(stdoutScanner.Text())
    }
}()

io.WriteString(f, "match (n) return count(n);\n")
time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

io.WriteString(f, "match (n) return count(n) + 123;\n")
time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
```

**Aside 1:** In your example, you don’t need `sh -c`, because you’re not using any features of the shell. You can avoid the overhead of an additional shell process by running `cypher-shell` directly:

```
cmd := exec.Command("cypher-shell", "-u", "neo4j", "-p", "121314", "--format", "plain")
```

**Aside 2:** Do not discard returned `error` values in production code.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you very much for the answer and aside notes. Sure, I skip the error handling in the examples just to keep them short.