# Run bash script in TTY mode

Tags: linux, go, tty

I have a bash script and I run the script using `exec.Command`,

But the bash script required a TTY mode, my question how in Go could I run this bash script in TTY mode?
Is it possible?

Comment: Take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55976962/2125671